# Getting CMake Error with Protobuf Library in the configuration of OpenCV in Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I followed [this](https://www.theta.co.nz/news-blogs/tech-blog/object-detection-on-a-raspberry-pi/) tutorial to install OpenCV and all the steps worked until I reached the Install part. I did the following:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.3.0/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

The command performed several tests and showed the General configuration for OpenCV 3.3.0 but at the end I got the following error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
Protobuf_LIBRARY
    linked by target "opencv_dnn_modern" in directory /home/pi/opencv_contrib-3.3.0/modules/dnn_modern

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have a `opencv_contrib-3.3.0` directory though instead of `opencv_contrib` that's why I included the -3.3.0 in the `make`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue through the following steps:

1. Deleting the build folder in the opencv directory
2. Recreating the build folder: `mkdir build`
3. Moving to that build directory: `cd build`
4. Adding the following line in the `make`: `-D BUILD_opencv_dnn_modern=OFF`
   and running it as follows:

   ```
   cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
   -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
   -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
   -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
   -D BUILD_opencv_dnn_modern=OFF \
   -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
   -D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON \
   -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.3.0/modules \
   -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
   ```